# Promises not handled through Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to perform some actions once all my data are loaded but I have troubles with promises that are not handled properly.

```
export function waitForAll() {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        Promise.all([
            dispatch(getCharacteristics()),
            dispatch(getItems())]
        ).then(()=>{
            let state = getState();
             dispatch(update(state))
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

And here are the 2 functions called for this promise :

```
export function getCharacteristics() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.get('api/charac').then((response) =>
        {
            dispatch(fetchCharacteristics(response.data));
        }).catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

And

```
export function getItems() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.get('api/45897').then((response) =>
        {
            dispatch(fetchItems(response.data.equipements));
        }).catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

My states are not updated, that means that my promises are not handled properly, I've initial state like [].

An alternative could be componentDidMount() in React to call that function but I'm not sure how to verify that BOTH states are loaded correctly (different components)

I can't figure out how I can make it work, any help would be welcome!

Comment: do you need to return axios.get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't actually returning the promise. Arrange your code to return the promise (not just resolve it) and then you'll be able to leverage `Promise.all`

Example:

```js
async function promise1 () {
    const promise = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    return promise.json();
};
async function promise2 () {
    const promise = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2');
    return promise.json();
};


async function getAllPromises() {
    const results = await Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()]);
    console.log(results);
};

getAllPromises();
```

Basically, I think you can just return the `axios.<httpverb>`

Example (best guess as I won't be able to get your code to run):

```
export function waitForAll() {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        Promise.all([
            dispatch(getCharacteristics()),
            dispatch(getItems())]
        ).then(()=>{
            let state = getState();
             dispatch(update(state))
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}

export function getCharacteristics(dispatch) {
    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) {
        axios.get('api/charac').then((response) =>
        {
            resolve(dispatch(fetchCharacteristics(response.data)));
        }).catch(error =>{
                reject(error);
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}

export function getItems(dispatch) {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject)  {
        axios.get('api/45897').then((response) =>
        {
            resolve(dispatch(fetchItems(response.data.equipements)));
        }).catch(error =>{
                reject(error);
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I'm going to try this! I was using this example to help me out but with no success : https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/723#issuecomment-139927639

Comment: Please upvote or mark as answer if this is helping you solve your problem

Comment: Basically, you need to make you're returning an actual promise in the functions that are being called in your `Promise.all`

Comment: This is working perfectly! It's pretty hard to mix all those syntaxes between the dispatch of my middleware plus the promises to handle. Huge thanks

Comment: Yea, I would structure it different and use async/await (compatible with promises). It makes your code a lot cleaner and shorter

Comment: Interested about this since promises are such a pain to read, do you have any examples?

Comment: If you post another question I'd be happy to answer. But essentially, just don't use `.then` or `.catch`. Just return a `promise` at all times so it can be used with `await`. Anytime you use `await` you'll have to make sure it's parent function is an `async` function. Promises are much easier than callbacks. They just take a little bit of time to get used to. Once you understand them, you will never go back.

Comment: I will give it a check through documentation when I'm going to refactor these promises then, thanks for advice and explanations!

Comment: I updated my answer to show a more simplified use of your setup. Notice how `.then` is never used. Instead, `await` is used.